# MySQL -- WHERE clause without reducing rowset

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

The problem is that not all of the sales clerks are included because of the WHERE clause reducing the rowset ...

```
  SELECT c.id, 
         c.name, 
         COUNT(o.id) AS count, 
         o.id, 
         o.date
    FROM clerks c JOIN 
         orders o ON c.id = o.id
   WHERE o.date BETWEEN $date AND $date2
GROUP BY c.id
```

There are 250 clerks, but this only returns about 50 because the WHERE clause reduces the rowset. Is there some MySQL Magic to include the clerks with a Count of 0 if they do not meet the WHERE clause?

I am trying to avoid subqueries, because every single one I try is so slow.

Comment: use a `left join` and move the `where` condition to the `join` clause.

Comment: @vkp So, LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.id AND WHERE o.date BETWEEN ... ?

Comment: no `LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.id AND o.date BETWEEN ... `

Comment: @vkp Extremely slow. I had to kill the process in phpMyAdmin. Tables are indexed on every column that this query touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, 
         c.name, 
         COUNT(o.id) AS count, 
         o.id, 
         o.date
    FROM clerks c LEFT JOIN 
         orders o ON c.id = o.id and o.date BETWEEN $date AND $date2
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: This just hangs. I had to kill the process in phpMyAdmin

Comment: can you make SQL Fiddle ?

Comment: Even though it runs slow on my schema. This is the best answer yet.